# The path is null in Image Picker

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen that is used to update information, it shows information about the photo or route that is saved with other fields.

But I have the scenario that the photo will not always be updated, the camera will not always open.

So since I'm not always going to use the camera, when saving the information I get an error that path is null.

I am using an Image Picker to open the camera and take a picture.

My code:

```
     String fotousuarioo;
    
    class crudperfilfotobase extends State<CrudPerfilFotoBase>{
    
       Future OpenCamera() async {
        final pickedFile = await  ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera); 
        setState(() {
          if (pickedFile != null) {
            image = File(pickedFile.path);// direccien de la foto
          }else{
          }});}
    
      Widget NewPhoto(){
        return Container(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            child: CircleAvatar(
              child: Align(
                child:TextButton (
                  onPressed:EliminarImagenF2,
                  child: CircleAvatar(        
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.cancel, ),),),),
                 backgroundImage: new FileImage(image) ,),),);
    }
    
      Widget PhotoDataBase(){
        return new Container(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage('http://...${fotousuarioo}'),
              child: Align(
              child:TextButton (
                  onPressed:OpenCamera,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                   child: Icon(
                      Icons.edit,
                     ),), ),),),),);
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Container(
         child: Container(
             child: image == null ? Databasephoto(): Newphoto(),),);
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    }
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
        class crudperfil extends State<CrudPerfil>{
         appBar: new AppBar(
                  title: new Text("Editar Perfil"),
                  centerTitle: true,
                  leading:  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
                    onPressed: () {
                    }
                  ),
                  actions:[
                   IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.black),
                      onPressed: () {
            if(KeyFormValidaciones.currentState.validate() && image.path.isNotEmpty  ){
             
               editar2perfilmodel.setfotoCrud = image.path; 
            }}),]),
        
        
         child: FutureBuilder(
         future: MethodGetData(),
          List  busqueda = snapshot.data;
           fotousuarioo = busqueda[i].FotoUsuario;
        Container(
                  child: ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                      children:[
                        SizedBox(height: 18,),
                        image == null ? CrudPerfilFotoBase():Text("ddddd"),
                        SizedBox(height: 18,),
                        FullName(NombreUsuario),
                        SizedBox(height: 18,),
                        CorreoF2(Correo),
                        SizedBox(height: 18,),
                        PrecioServivicio(PrecioServicio), 
        ]),), );
        }
```

Image:

[image]

How could I solve that? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to save the pickedFile to firebase storage, get the image url and display it in your widget.

Comment: that's what I do, I save the image when you use the camera but the inconvenience is when you don't open the camera, you don't want to update the image and only update the other fields.
 I get the error

Comment: please specify the version of Image_Picker library and flutter version and your devices android  version, also check on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22p%3A+image_picker%22 if there is similar issue

Comment: I do not think it is the version, the problem was that the Open Camera method was not activated and that is why the path was null but now the path is not null but it gives me an error in the Multipartrequest.fromPath() with the path file that comes from from the database